# How to convert speech to text in python - opus file format

Tags: python, nlp, speech-to-text, speech, opus

I have some `.opus` audio files that need to be converted to text in order to run some analytics. I am aware that there is the Python [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) package that can do this with `.wav` files as demonstrated in [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/).

Does anyone know how to convert `.opus` files to text, or convert `.opus` to `.wav`?

I have tried the Python [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) package with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which employs [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) and the `os` library to first convert all `.opus` files in the specified directory to `.wav`, and then perform speech recognition on the resulting `.wav` files using the `speech_recognition` module:

### Solution

```py
import os
import speech_recognition as sr

path = './audio-files/'
file_type_to_convert = ".opus"
file_type_to_recognize = ".wav"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(file_type_to_convert):
        os.system("ffmpeg -i \"{}\" -vn \"{}\"".format(path + filename,
                                                       path + filename[:-len(file_type_to_convert)] +
                                                       file_type_to_recognize))
recognizer = sr.Recognizer()  # Instantiate recognizer
rec_output = {}  # Create list to store output of speech recognized files

# Iterate over each file of specified type to be recognized
for file_to_recognize in os.listdir(path):
    if file_to_recognize.endswith(file_type_to_recognize):
        audio = sr.AudioFile(path + file_to_recognize)
        with audio as source:
            audio_data = recognizer.record(audio)
        # Recognize & append output
        # Note: google recognizer is online only, sphinx is the only offline option which uses CMU Sphinx engine
        rec_output[file_to_recognize[:-len(file_type_to_recognize)]] = recognizer.recognize_google(audio_data,
                                                                                                   language='en-US')

# Display each file's output
for key, val in rec_output.items():
    print(key)
    print(val)
    # Output: 
    # File name
    # Recognized words in each file
```